# C#: while versus if

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, contains

I want to only accept uppercase two letter abbreviations for state that are: AK, WA, OR, CA, AZ, NM, CO, or UT. If the input is not one of those, request a new input from the user to correct. My code below works to filter results, but when I enter "UT" or "WA" it does not exit the while loop and continues.

```
Write("State (We only ship to AK, WA, OR, CA, AZ, NM, CO, or UT):\t");
            stateName = Convert.ToString(ReadLine().ToUpper());
            while (!stateName.Contains("AK") || !stateName.Contains("WA") || !stateName.Contains("OR") 
                || !stateName.Contains("CA") || !stateName.Contains("AZ") || !stateName.Contains("NM") 
                || !stateName.Contains("CO") || !stateName.Contains("UT"))
            {
                Write("Error: We do not ship to {0}. We ONLY ship to AK, WA, OR, CA, AZ, NM, CO, or UT\t", stateName);
                stateName = Convert.ToString(ReadLine().ToUpper());
            }
```

Revising it further, I got it to work with:

```
Write("State (We only ship to AK, WA, OR, CA, AZ, NM, CO, or UT):\t");
            stateName = Convert.ToString(ReadLine().ToUpper());
            if (stateName != "AK" || stateName != "WA" || stateName != "OR"
                || stateName != "CA" || stateName != "AZ" || stateName != "NM"
                || stateName != "CO" || stateName != "UT")
            {
                Write("Error: We do not ship to {0}. We ONLY ship to AK, WA, OR, CA, AZ, NM, " +
                    "CO, or UT\t", stateName);
                stateName = Convert.ToString(ReadLine().ToUpper());
            }
```

My question is why didn't the while loop work if the logic was very similar? And is the `!variableName` different than `variableName != value`?

Comment: A useful tip not only for this case but for all general cases like this: put a debugger and go through your code line by line, you will understand why your code runs like that. See [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: `!variableName` is same as `variableName != true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your logic, you should be using `And &&` operator instead of `Or ||`:

```
while (
    !stateName.Contains("AK") && !stateName.Contains("WA") && !stateName.Contains("OR")
    && !stateName.Contains("CA") && !stateName.Contains("AZ") && !stateName.Contains("NM")
    && !stateName.Contains("CO") && !stateName.Contains("UT"))
```

[image]

I assume you are learning so I went along with this code. In real world scenarios, you should use array to check for so many conditions like this instead (you will need to know `for` loop and `Array`).